# Copy in use files with security Permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, robocopy, volume-shadow-copy

Is there a free Windows utility that will let me copy folders and sub folder contents with their NTFS security permissions and let me copy in use files?

Comment: This would be entirely based on how the file is open.  You can already copy a file that is open using the default copy procedure.

Comment: Like Outlook PST files, for instance.

Comment: I mentioned "...NTFS security permissions **and** let me copy **in use** files"

Comment: Anyways, I've used RoboCopy before and love it since it copies sub folders with their corresponding security permissions, but says "access denied" when it tries to copy over a locked PST file, for instance.

Comment: Yes...Because the file is locked by the process.  Its because of the way Outlook opens the file.  A second time through reading your question I realized you simply want to copy and `transfer` the same NTFS security permissions as the original to the copy.  The problem you face is, if the process locks the file, you will find it very difficult to unlock the file and not cause cause corruption issues with the original.